# Running Gatling tests in docker

Tags: docker, fatjar

We are looking in to using Gatling as a load-tester for an application we are developing. 
Im pretty unexperienced with Scala in general but as I understand the Scala-requirement are pretty modest so I hope that shouldnt be a problem.
 I want to be able to package our tests as a docker-image that I could spin-up and run as part of the deployment-pipeline. How do I acheieve that in the best-way?
 - One way would be to package as a fat-jar that is runnable from commandline is one way. Are there any other options? 
- How do I create a fat-jar using maven? Can I use the the `maven-assembly-plugin` as I would do for java?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Gatling and Scala shouldn't impact how you do things in Maven. You might have a better chance of getting answer by removing scala and gatling tags and adding maven tag.